# Make a copy of an Excel file as a CSV without having Excel "re-open" the file as a CSV

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

I have several dozen Microsoft Excel files in `xlsx` format.  These files are the "master" copy for editing and include various formatting to make them easier to edit.

However, the data from these files is imported into a CMS as CSV, so ultimately I need to generate CSV files.

To generate the CSV files, this is what I do currently.

1. Click `File` in the Ribbon.
2. Click `Save as`.
3. Select `CSV UTF-8`.
4. Click `Save`.

However, when I do this, Excel automatically closes the `xlsx` file and opens the new `CSV UTF-8` file.  This is a problem because the formatting is still there, so it *looks* like the `xlsx` file, and sometimes I make additional changes to the CSV file, when the changes need to be made to the master file.

For now, I have made it a habit to very carefully close the CSV after export and then re-open the `xlsx` file to prevent this kind of mistake.

How can I generate a CSV file from an `xlsx` file without having Excel close the `xlsx` file and open the CSV file?

**EDIT**

The `xlsx` files are stored in Google Drive, and sometimes users update them via Google Sheets. So I can't convert to `xlsm` because then the files will no longer be editable in Sheets.

Comment: This will probably require to do the Save As in a VBA macro, which requires converting the workbooks from `.xlsx` to `.xlsm`. Does this work for you?

Comment: @harrymc Unfortunately no, because it seems Google Sheets can't edit `xlsm`.  I've updated the question.

Comment: It's not really opening the csv file after the SaveAs; rather you are seeing the file as you last saved it. (The effect is the same, however). That is by design and you can't change it. You will need to close the file after your SaveAs.  And then re-open your template file if you want to do more work on it.  (or use VBA)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to change the behavior of Excel without VBA or an add-in.

The following add-ins might be able to help:

- [XLTools](https://xltools.net/excel-export-to-csv/) (commercial)
- [excel-csv-import](https://github.com/Emurasoft/excel-csv-import)
- [CSV Import+Export](https://www.emeditor.com/related-software/csv-importexport-an-excel-add-in/)

But perhaps it's better to avoid doing the Save As in Excel and do
it rather with a PowerShell script. This way you would also be able to
save multiple Excel worksheets with one script.

Here is an example PowerShell function (totally untested) :

```
Function ExcelToCsv ($File) {
    $myDir = "D:\Excel"
    $excelFile = "$myDir\" + $File + ".xlsx"
    $Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
    $wb = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($excelFile)
    foreach ($ws in $wb.Worksheets) {
        $ws.SaveAs("$myDir\" + $File + ".csv", 6)
    }
    $Excel.Quit()
}
```

An example usage (untested):

```
$FileName = "\path\to\workbook"
ExcelToCsv -File $FileName
```